# Calculate Intersection point of 2 Lines with angle

Tags: angle, intersection-theory, fixed-points

I would like to calculate an intersection point of two lines in a 2D area.
I think it should be really simple but i cannot figure it out.

I have two points P1(x,y), P2(x,y) and 2 angles alpha and beta.
I know all 4 values and I would like to calculate the Intersection Point I out of it.
I cannot add picutres now but the link is below. Hope you can help me out
[(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzQHt.jpg)

Comment: So like $f(x) = a x +b$ and $g(x) = c x + d$ and then having them meet?

Comment: And lines meeting is just setting them equal. So just need to figure out how you can translate angles to the slope of the line.

Comment: Yeah that is teh quesiton how i get to this... is there a posibility to calculate with angle. Have you checked my picture?

Comment: I'm trying to help you figuring it out. How could you use sin and cos in this case?

Comment: You should calculate the tangent of the 2 angles ($\tan \alpha = $ opposite side/adjascent side) and deduce the equations o the 2 lines

Comment: equations = 0 ? I didnt get it, it is over 30 years ago since my school has ended. I am sry

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Solve for the two unknowns from their equations

$$ \frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=-\cot \alpha $$
$$ \frac{y-y_2}{x-x_2}=-\tan \beta $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slope-point form - to figure out the point of intersection.

The first step is to deduce the equations of the two lines. The slope of the first line is tan(90 + $\alpha$) == - cot$\alpha$ . So the equation of the first line is $y - P_{1,y} = - cot\alpha(x - P_{1,x})$. Similarly, the equation of the second line is $y - P_{2,y} = -tan\beta(x - P_{2,x})$.

Then you can easily calculate the point of intersection by solving the two equations simultaneously.